# Vue.js Can't iterate through object in method

Tags: javascript, methods, vue.js, vuejs2, scoping

I have a Vue.js component that has a data variable that's a JSON object and I've made a method that's meant to easily find items within this object by key, recursively.

Here it is:

```
getJsonItem(lookup, obj=this.cardInfo) {
  for (item in obj) {
    if (item == lookup) {
      return obj[item];
    } else if (obj[item] instanceof Object) {
      getJsonItem(lookup, obj[item]);
    }
  }
},
```

Now, this worked perfectly fine in the console outside of Vue JS, but when I try running it from within Vue JS as a method I get a "ReferenceError: item is not defined" error.

Is there something funny going on with the scoping of variables in Vue JS that stops me from referencing the 'item' variable that's declared in the for loop?

I'm sure it's probably something simple I'm not seeing.

Comment: I think you are confusing with v-for directive, Please check here : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 11):

You have to use `var`, `let` or `const` for a variable declaration (in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)):

```
for (const item in obj)
     ^^^^^
```

Comment: Can't +1 you for lack of rep, but thanks. I didn't even think of that, you helped a ton!

Comment: omg, Kyle! Just mark it with tick as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define `item` with the keyword `const` to make it a block-scope variable.

Next add `this` before the recursive call. Don't forget to define `cardInfo` within the `data` section.

You would also want to stick to Vue linting standards (I use ESLint when I created my project) so that you should use triple equal and delete semicolons etc.

Try this, it correctly logged the result into the console for me:

```
data () {
  return () {
    cardInfo: [
      // your data
    ]
  }
},
methods: {
  getJsonItem (lookup, obj = this.cardInfo) {
    for (const item in obj) {
      if (item === lookup) {
        console.log(obj[item])
      } else if (obj[item] instanceof Object) {
        this.getJsonItem(lookup, obj[item])
      }
    }
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.getJsonItem('brand')
}
```

If you call your method inside your template not your script you would not need to add `this` before it.